# Difference of columns having numbers in 2 different files and write the greater of numbers

Tags: shell, unix, awk, scripting

I have 2 different files having a single column with text values

File1 (these numbers are text)

20160303114651
20160304144552
20160307133942

File2 (only single record exists as text in this file)

20160304144552

I want to subtract the line in second file from every line  in the first file, and if their difference is greater than 0, then write the number from the first file into file3

Expected output of file3

20160307133942

Could anyone please provide the awk or unix script for this?

Comment: Hi there. StackExchange is not a code writing service. Please attempt the solve the problem yourself and if you have any questions about specific issues come back and post a new question

Comment: What you want is trivial but the lack of effort you have put into asking this question is currently being reflected in the lack of reasonable answers you are getting. Create a [mcve] and show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this,

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=`cat file2`
var2=`cat file1 | cut -d' ' -f1`
sub=$(( $var1 - $var2 ))
test $sub -gt 0 && echo $var2 > file3
```